# ast.literal_eval() malformed node or string while converting a string with list of array()s

Tags: python, numpy, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a string, which is a list of numpy arrays.
The string looks like

```
k = '[array([  0, 269, 175, 377]), array([  0,  56, 149, 163])]'
```

When I do

```
ast.literal_eval(k)
```

I get an error saying malformed node or string.

What is the problem here? Is there any better way to convert it back to a list?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: `array(…)` is a call, not a literal anything. You’ll need to create the string with only regular lists or use something before/other than `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: You should probably avoid doing this in the first place. Why are you getting these strings?

Comment: Is there a reason these are serialized as arrays, not as lists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`ast.literal_eval` doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.

It is not possible to use literal eval here. Find where these strings are generated in the first place, and implement a proper serialization there - for example using [`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this is a good approach.

```
from numpy import array
import ast
import re
k = '[array([  0, 269, 175, 377]), array([  0,  56, 149, 163])]'
val = re.findall(r"\((.*?)\)", k)
val = list(map(ast.literal_eval, val))
val = list(map(array, val))
print(val)
```

**Output:**

```
[array([  0, 269, 175, 377]), array([  0,  56, 149, 163])]
```

- Using Regex to extract content between `()`
- Apply `ast.literal_eval`
- Apply `np.array`

Comment: Clever. Works as long as the shape of the OP's data never changes -- I wouldn't go with this as a long-term approach, but could see it as a temporary/interim workaround until whatever is generating the strings in question gets fixed.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. I agree, it is not a proper solution. Best is to fix at the source of OP's input.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array
k = '[array([  0, 269, 175, 377]), array([  0,  56, 149, 163])]'
k = eval(k)
print(f"k = {k}, type of k = {type(k)}")
print(type(k[0]))
```

**Output:**

```
k = [array([  0, 269, 175, 377]), array([ 0, 56])], type of k = <class 'list'>

<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: The whole point of `literal_eval()` is to avoid using `eval()`, since the latter is dangerous in production code.