# np.where with arbitrary number of conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, abstract-syntax-tree

### Problem

This question: [Numpy where function multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16343752/8565438) asks how to use `np.where` with two conditions. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16343791/8565438) suggests to use the `&` operator between conditions, which works if we have a low number of conditions which can be typed. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31413800/1566221) suggests using the [`np.logical_and`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html), which can take only two arguments.

This thread: [Numpy "where" with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions) also discusses multiple conditions for `np.where`, but the number of conditions are known in advance.

I am looking for a way to evaluate an `np.where` expression without knowing the number of conditions in advance.

---

### Reproducible setup

I have a 2D array:

```
arr = \
np.array([[1,2,3,4],
          [4,5,6,7],
          [9,8,7,6],
          [0,1,0,1],
          [9,7,6,5]])
```

Select the rows which have, for example, index 1 element larger than 5, index 2 element larger than 3. To do that, I do:

```
res = arr[np.where((arr[:,1]>5) & (arr[:,2]>4))]
```

`res` is then:

```
array([[9, 8, 7, 6],
       [9, 7, 6, 5]])
```

as expected.

But what if I have these conditions as lists? The above example would be:

```
cols = [1,2] # arbitrary length list
tholds = [5,4] # arbitrary length list
```

These two lists are unknown length in advance, but they have the same length.

**How can I get `res` using the `cols` and `tholds` lists?**

---

### What I have tried

Use `ast.literal_eval` to define:

```
filterstring = "&".join([f"(pdist[:,{col}]>{th})" for col, th in zip(cols,tholds)])
```

which evaluates to `(pdist[:,1]>5)&(pdist[:,2]>4)`, ie what we had above within `np.where()` when the conditions are typed out manually.

However, `ast.literal_eval(f"np.where({filterstring})")` gives an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-1aaff20de82f> in <module>()
----> 1 ast.literal_eval(f"np.where({filterstring})")

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/ast.py in _convert_num(node)
     53         elif isinstance(node, Num):
     54             return node.n
---> 55         raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
     56     def _convert_signed_num(node):
     57         if isinstance(node, UnaryOp) and isinstance(node.op, (UAdd, USub)):

ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x7f41daa21f10>
```

So this did not work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50589892/8565438) to the question [ast.literal_eval() malformed node or string while converting a string with list of array()s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50589770/ast-literal-eval-malformed-node-or-string-while-converting-a-string-with-list/50589874#50589874) confirms that this is not the right approach.

---

**EDIT:**

The suggestion to use `np.where`s in a succession works fine for this particular example, but is not really what I look for. I would want to call `np.where` once, not multiple times evaluating one condition only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by combining a reordered view of the columns of your array (which is a fancy way of saying "use a list of indexes") with a broadcast comparison, reduced over rows with `np.all`

```
>>> arr[np.where(np.all(arr[:,cols] > thds, axis=1))]
array([[9, 8, 7, 6],
       [9, 7, 6, 5]])
```

As your first link indicates (and as mentioned in the Note at the top of the [documentation for np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)), there is actually no need for `np.where` in this case; it's only slowing things down. You can use a boolean list to slice a Numpy array, so you don't need to change the boolean list to a list of indexes. Since `np.all`, like the `&` operator, returns a Numpy array of boolean values, there is also no need for `np.asarray` or `np.nonzero` (as suggested in the aforementioned note):

```
>>> arr[np.all(arr[:,cols] > thds, axis=1)]
array([[9, 8, 7, 6],
       [9, 7, 6, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried to avoid eval. It has some security implications.

You could to it iteratively, like so

```
def unknown_conditions(arr, cols, tholds):

    for col, thold in zip(cols, tholds):
        arr = arr[np.where(arr[:, col] > thold)]
    
    return arr
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a good workaround on not actually using multiple conditions with `np.where`. If an answer is not added which does this within `np.where()`, I'll accept this, as it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could accumulate the number of met conditions and then call the `np.where` function once. From there it would be very easy to mix and/or combination from the conditions.

(Conceptually very similar to academy's suggestion.)

```py
def filter_by_conditions(arr, cols, tholds):
    n_conditions = len(cols)
    bool_accumulator = np.zeros(arr.shape[0])
    for c, t in zip(cols, tholds):
        bool_accumulator += (arr[:, c] > t).astype(int)

    return arr[np.where(bool_accumulator) == n_conditions]
```